# How to host a single HTML page in Netlify?

Tags: web, web-hosting, netlify, cloud-hosting

I want to host a website online.
Mine is a simple html file with some external CSS and javascript.
Could you please let me know how can I host this HTML page as a website in Netlify?
As Netlify suggest I tried providing relevant GITHUB links, but still this gives me Page not found error because of incorrect link
Do I have any other free hosting sites where I can get this done?

Comment: Netlify should be good for this. Please clarify the name of your site, and list some build logs so we can better understand what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

You have twio options to deploy to Netlify,

You can use version control with GitHub or [Netlify Drop](https://app.netlify.com/drop)

To use GitHub, follow this instruction: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/27/a-step-by-step-guide-deploying-a-static-site-or-single-page-app/

With drop, you will only need to drag and drop a folder with your site’s HTML, CSS, and JS files using their interface, and Netlify will publish it on your website.

To use Drop, follow this link: https://app.netlify.com/drop

Answer (score 3):

Netlify is a good solution for host static files, but it need a git repository.

Because you can't touch into Netlify server to upload your file, Netlify is not your own VPS.

That's why everything you need is:

- Create a git repository (github/gitlab/etc)
- Connect that repository to Netlify.
- Deploy

That's all!

Comment: This can't be right because at the minimum it also needs a CI configuration to work, isn't that right?

Comment: If you need CI, you will need CI configuration obviously. I am just talking about hosting solution.